# SQL Filter query repeated results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012 and executing the following query:

```
SELECT StockAct.CodAlm, StockAct.CodArt, MovStock.units
FROM MovStock,
     StockAct
WHERE MovStock.CodArt = StockAct.CodArt
  AND MovStock.CodAlm = StockAct.CodAlm
```

And the result is like:

```
CodAlm  CodArt  Units

0001    BA2 -25
0001    BA2 -25
0001    BA2 -25
0002    BA2 -9
0002    BA2 -9
0002    BA2 -9
0002    BA2 -9
0003    BA2 60
0003    BA2 60
0003    BA2 60
0003    BA2 60
```

The goal would be to make a query or something that returns the repeated values in zeros (except the first):

```
0001    BA2 -25
0001    BA2 0
0001    BA2 0
0002    BA2 -9
0002    BA2 0
0002    BA2 0
0002    BA2 0
0003    BA2 60
0003    BA2 0
0003    BA2 0
0003    BA2 0
```

The values ALWAYS repeat (so they are 1 1 1, 2 2 2 ... n n n).

The consecutive results could be 3 or 4 considering every single case.

`GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` are NOT working because the query returns a lot of more columns that have different values and they are not equal (I only show these to ease this example).

In other programming languages this could be solved with something like: if codalm and codart match with last result then show 0, else show *units.value*.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your tables data (`MovStock` and `StockAct`) in this example?

Comment: SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.  There is no first row in a group unless another column explicitly defines the ordering.

Comment: I'd like but they're too big :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to assign row numbers. Then use a `case` expression to select the actual units on the first row for each group and 0 otherwise.

```
select codalm,codart,
case when rn = 1 then units else 0 end as units
from (
SELECT StockAct.CodAlm, StockAct.CodArt,MovStock.units
,row_number() over(partition by StockAct.CodAlm, StockAct.CodArt,MovStock.units 
                   order by StockAct.CodAlm, StockAct.CodArt,MovStock.units) as rn
FROM MovStock
JOIN StockAct ON MovStock.CodArt = StockAct.CodArt AND MovStock.CodAlm = StockAct.CodAlm) t
```

Comment: I believe you need `order by codalm, codart, rn` for this to work consistently.

Comment: @GordonLinoff.. i think `order by null` would work the same as `order by codalm, codart, rn`..correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: Why the last character? 't'

Comment: it is a table-alias for the derived table. you can name it anything.

Comment: @vkp . . . I don't think so.  The rows  have to be returned in a specific order for the code to work.  So, you need to specify the ordering.

Comment: @GordonLinoff well, this way it's working 4 me, and order by doesn't seem to work in this kind of query :) thanks!

Comment: @jinfo . . . It *appears* to work, but there is not a guarantee that it will always work, unless you have the `order by`.